# Программно подписываем ЭЦП PDF

Tags: c++, qt, шифрование, цифровая-подпись

Здравствуйте.

Для системы нужно разработать модуль, выгружающий отчеты в PDF и подписывающий их ЭЦП оператора, работавшего в этот момент в системе. Система -- распределенное ПО с серверной частью и клиентской. Выгрузка отчета нужна на клиентском терминале. Клиентский терминал -- десктопное QT-приложение на C++.
Собственно вопрос: как программно подписать PDF?

Не ищу готового решения, достаточно будет наводящих ссылок или слов.

Comment: @Cerbo вроде бы вопрос один — как программно подписывать PDF — а остальное просто для контекста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как понимаю речь идёт о криптографической подписи, при этом нужно её уметь с помощью C++ кода ставить? Есть например [Adobe PDF Library SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html) или [Adobe Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/documentation.html), если не первая то вторая точно может делать ЭЦП. Это вроде платные библиотеки зато от создателя PDF. Также есть и бесплатные решения, например [VersyPDF](https://github.com/sybrexsys/VersyPDF) библиотека, она заявляет в описании что может делать Digital Signatures т.е. то что нужно.

Кстати, наверняка главная проблема не в том как поставить эту подпись, а в том как поднять всю инфраструктуру криптографическую, в частности вопрос в том какой алгоритм подписи можно использовать, какие сертификаты нужны, кто их будет и как выдавать, возможно вы хотите даже личные ключи подписи хранить на смарт картах или USB токенах. Вообщем если криптографические вопросы решены, то подпись поставить не так сложно, вот например даже [Адоб описывает](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf) где и в каком виде в документе эта подпись должна находиться. Я например работаю на криптографическую фирму и мы как раз занимаемся вопросами создания оборудования и программного обеспечения для различного применения криптографии.